# PyQt4: Create many buttons from dict dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a dictionary that contains about 25 keys and values.  Each one of those keys is going to be a button.  Is there a dynamic way to make each key a button rather than  typing the code for each individual key?  Something along the lines of:

```
for key in dict:
     ...
     QtGui.QPushButton(key, self)
     ...
```

I know there will be more code than that.  I am just wondering if something like that will work with less hassle than typing out each one individually.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes that will work. But I recommend keeping a reference somwhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure try this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from functools import partial


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, mapping):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.buttons = []
        for key, value in mapping.items():
            self.buttons.append(QtGui.QPushButton(key, self))
            self.buttons[-1].clicked.connect(partial(handleButton, data=value))
            layout.addWidget(self.buttons[-1])



def handleButton(self, data="\n"):
    print (data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    buttons = {'foo': 'bar', 'something': 'other'}
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(buttons)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now will that output the buttons in the same order they are in the dict?  And what if I wanted a specific order?

Comment: Nvm, I got it.  Thanks again.  This was exactly what I needed to know.